# Xpath syntax to extract all player elements with sport = NBA

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm attempting to extract all player data for players under the sport = NBA. How do I write the Xpath syntax to extract that data. The API feed I'm working with is located here:

https://www.fanduel.com/api/grindersplayerprices?date=2014-11-11

I'd also like to limit the results to the minimum Game: Start Time within the NBA node. So with sport = NBA there might be multiple start times. I don't care what the start time is, but I only want the minimum start time within the NBA node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all NBA players your could do this

```
//fixturelist[sport='NBA']/player
```

Not sure about the other requirement. Please provide more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the help - that works. The other requirement isn't a must since I can filter it out easily in my spreadsheet.